# Can you ask a question with many questions inside of it?

Tags: support

Let's say. I would like to know some things of the [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

Should I make the questions I need to know separately or all in one question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ask them separately, but preferably not all at once. It may be that the response to your first question enlightens you about the others as well. In any case, it's slightly rude to take up too much space on the front page.

Comment: Agreed, while noting that standards of rudeness sure have increased since I was a kid!